# CouchDB with PHP (using cURL), but how?

Tags: php, curl, couchdb

First, I want to tell you that I am not interested for solutions with PHP frameworks such as *phpillow*, *php-on-couch*, *sag* or similar. I want to create a connection to the CouchDB *exclusively* with cURL in PHP file, as in the example below.

1st Example:

```
<?php

 // Get a list of databases

 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:5984/_all_dbs');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-type: application/json',
    'Accept: */*'
 ));

 $response = curl_exec($ch);

 curl_close($ch);

 echo $response;

?>
```

2nd Example:

```
 <?php

 // Get a document 'customer' from specific db 'customers' 

 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:5984/customers/customer');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-type: application/json',
    'Accept: */*'
 ));

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'myDBusername:myDBpass');

 $response = curl_exec($ch);

 curl_close($ch);

 echo $response;
?>
```

What I know so far? I know how to create CRUD (create, read, update, delete) in PHP file using exclusively cURL, above example. I know how to use cURL from command prompt.

What I asking from you? I am asking you the following:

1. How to create (complex) search using CouchDB views in PHP file with cURL?
2. How to create complex search using some input informations from HTML form?

Comment: May I ask *why* you don't want to use an existing library? It would certainly have its advantages.

Comment: While I am no Couch expert, cURL is used to make HTTP requests. It isn't used to create views. You'll need to render HTML from your CRUD requests in some fashion.

Comment: I'm at the stage of learning and I'd like to know what exactly happens when I make some queries.

Comment: I know how to make **views**, **reduce**, **reReduce** and etc. using **JavaScipt** in **CouchDB**, but I don't know how to retrieve data from queries and how to make queries with **cURL** in _php_ file.

Comment: I also know how to use **views** in _php_ file but I do not know how to create some queries of them.

Answer (score 0):

To query a view in CouchDB, you make a get request to a URL like /$DB/_design/$DDOC/_view/$VIEW, where $DB is your database name, $DDOC is your design document name and $VIEW is the name of your view. You then append various parameters like "key", "startkey", "endkey", "sort" etc to the URL, depending on what kind of information you want the view to return.

See CouchDB's documentation at http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options

To do that with cURL in PHP, all you have to do is set the right query URL and method:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:5984/$DB/_design/$DDOC/_view/$VIEW");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'myDBusername:myDBpass');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. It would be good if you give a concrete example.
For example:
``

Comment: For example:
`
<?php

 // Get a document 'customer' from specific db 'customers' 

 $ch = curl_init();
 $query = "";
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:5984/'.$query);

?>
`

Comment: I ran into a problem where I added 'key=value' to my query and got a invalid json error.  After searching high and low I found you need to add %22value%22 to the query.  this seems to work.